# Nesting for loops in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In a batch file I have 2 for loops  like this

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%k in (%CurrentDirec%\list.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=1" %%l in (%cd%\pragma.txt) do (
    SourceFile.bat %%k %filenamecount% %%l
    )
)
```

My question is I will be calling `SourceFile.bat` using the for loops but the looping should happen only for the number of times as the variable `%%k` in the first for statement. It should not call the source file.bat as a combination of both the for loops.

Now its calling both the `sourcefile.bat` as a combination of both the for loops.

And also I want to call the `sourcefile.bat` with 3 parameters.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: If you only want to call `sourceFile.bat` `%%k` times, why are you calling it inside the inner `FOR` loop? What are the contents of `%cd%\pragma.txt`?

Comment: what are typical contents of %%k and %%l ? and for a typical value of each, what is the invocation of sourcefile.bat you want to achieve?